# Search for a word with Prefix in the column and copy the entire word with prefix to another column on the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I Download an excel file which has multiple Row's and endless columns.

In a particular Row we have data where every Cell is containing details of a specific product, Separated by Alt+Enter.

I have to pull the data of 2-3 such descriptions by copy paste to separate the product from the huge list.

Eg:-

```
_A_______B____________C____D___E___F___G______H_________________________________
   |  Product     | Range |A | B | C |D |description|....
________________________________________________________________________________
1  |  Apple       | R 1   |A1| B1| C1|D1| Description1
                                          Description2
                                          Description3
                                          Description4
________________________________________________________________________________
2  |  ball        | R 1   |A1| B1| C1|D1| Description1
                                          Description2
                                          Description3
                                          Description4
```

From the above example My Requirment is to copy Description Details with Prefix of Say DLL:123456 or LLM: 654321 and copy the same to the next Row.

This will help to seperate the product with perticular Description.

Comment: Let's make this clearer.  Do I have this right?  You have several descriptions in one cell, column H, for each row of items  that are indexed in column A and named in Column B.  If one of the descriptions in row 1, for example, the "Apple Row", should have a description with a prefix of  LLM: 654321 , then you want to copy that entire description and paste it to the "next row", which would be row #2, named "ball"?

Answer (score 0):

If this what you looking for :

APPLE       A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   2460    APPLE : 2460

```
                                    6521    APPLE : 6521
                                    4532    APPLE : 4532
                                    3021    APPLE : 3021
                                    1234    APPLE : 1234
```

BALL                                    6521    BALL : 6521
                                        4532    BALL : 4532
                                        3021    BALL : 3021
                                        1234    BALL : 1234

Then create a column and use this formula. You can also use your own prefix

=IF(ISBLANK(a2),LEFT(a1,(SEARCH(":",a1)) & " " &l2),a2&" : "&l2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm guessing you need:  This might get you started:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim rowArray() As Variant, rowArrayCounter As Long
Dim myStringArray, itemThatIwant As String, rowItIsIn As Long

'   The following code will find all instances of "LLM: 654321" in column "F"
'   It places the row number of each one into an array called rowArray()
'   and places the value of that item into a variable called itemThatIwant

'   The "split" function assumes that you enttered each list into a single cell
'   by using alt-enter to put them on individual lines within that cell.  If so, then 
'   the split delimiter would be chr(10), as below.  Otherwise it will probably be one space
'   but you will need to find the correct delimiter for this to work.

rowArrayCounter = 1
ReDim rowArray(1 To 1)
With Worksheets(1).Range("F1:F250")
    Set c = .Find("LLM: 654321", LookIn:=xlValues)' this text is what you change
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            myString = Split(c.Value, Chr(10)) ' split cell list into separate items
            For i = LBound(myString) To UBound(myString)
                If Left(myString(i), 11) = "LLM: 654321" Then
                    itemThatIwant = myString(i)
                    rowItIsIn = c.Row
                    ReDim Preserve rowArray(1 To rowArrayCounter)
                    rowArray(rowArrayCounter) = c.Row
                      ' do your events with data
                      ' the entire item (if found) is in the variable itemThatIwant
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John - I am new to Macro world. I was expecting a working Macro I tried running this but there was no result.. I am sure as this happened because of lack of knowledge for what and where to make the required necessary changes . I am not sure if you can help me on this. Thanks a Lot for the efforts and approch.

Comment: The example searched the page for your example text "LLM: 654321".  Look at the line that says "this text is what you change."  And you can change "LLM: 654321" to anything you are searching for.  I'm guessing that "LLM: 654321" was not on the page you searched.